# How to fix ImageArray load in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to learn Angular and stuck in the following Image array. Can anyone please explain what is the problem in my code and how to fix this ?

FilterAndImages.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
<title>First Angular</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy = 'price'">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <h3> {{product.name}} </h3>
            <p> {{product.description}} </p>
            <img ng-src="{{product.images[0].full}}" />
            <em class="pull-right">
                {{product.price | currency}}
                <br><button ng-show="product.canPurchase"> Add to Cart </button>
            </em>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('store', []);

var gems = [{
    name: 'Ruby',
    price: 2.95,
    description: 'This is Ruby on Rails :)',
    canPurchase: true,
    images: [
        {
            full: 'full.png',
            thumb: 'thump.jpg'
        },
    ]
},
{
    name: "Black Pearl",
    price: 1.5,
    description: "Jack Sparrow !!",
    canPurchase: false,
    images: [
        {
            full: 'full.png',
            thumb: 'thump.jpg'
        },
    ],
}];

app.controller('StoreController', function () {
    this.products = gems;
});
})();
```

I will be really thankful to you guys.

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: why are you repeating ul and not li??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a plunker example with your code , that makes the order ,check it here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/uVDl51EyRuwNmj428it1?p=preview

instead of `<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy ='price'">`

try to use ':' instead of '=' on the orderby:

`<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy :'-price'">`

Comment: Thanks @Theo. I have updated the code but the problem is still not fixed.

Comment: i changed a little bit your code and i think it works in my example.check it and tell me

Comment: I have fixed the issue by some changes in App.js...Thankyou for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems stands in the way you call the orderBy filter.

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy = 'price'">
```

should become:

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy: 'price'">
```

For further options on this feature please see [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: Thanks @morels for your input but this is not solving the issue.

Comment: @morels..The outputs blinks for a second and then got blank. There are no such error messages on the console.

Comment: However I have fixed the issue by some changes in App.js...Thankyou for your valuable time :)

Comment: It will keep not solving the issue until you do not provide more info on the issue since this is not a quiz... what does the console say?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.products = gems;
});
```

Comment: in the controllerAs pattern it is not used.